# apache in front of tomcat and redirect not working properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat, grails

I have a grails app running on an amazon linux server, I have a tomcat and added an apache on the front in order to have domain.com redirected to www.domain.com. After googling a lot I could make it work, but then I realised that when I tiped domain.com it was being redirected to www.domain.com// (two slashes at the end). Googling again I could make it work with the following configuration in a tomcat.conf file located in /etc/httpd/conf.d :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.domain.com
   ServerAlias domain.com
   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On

   ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/tomcat.error.log
   CustomLog /var/log/httpd/tomcat.log combined

   <Proxy *>
           Order deny,allow
           Allow from all
   </Proxy>

   ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
   ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
   RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

the problem is that now sometimes everything works as expected, but sometimes when I go to domain.com I get a download box asking to download a DMS file, and sometimes it works but showing the two slashes, and it also happened that when I entered domain.com it got converted to www.www.domain.com (two www's) so not sure what it's making this work fine sometimes and sometimes not.

Looking at the tomcat logs I can see this which I think it could be related:

```
Jul 05, 2016 11:02:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor     setErrorState
INFO: An error occurred in processing while on a non-container     thread. The connection will be closed immediately
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
```

EDIT 2: I removed the lines to do the redirect from domain.com to www.domain.com and I'm still having this issue where randomly I'm asked to download a file instead of being shown the site, and I could see in the JS console the next message:
Resource interpreted as document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "domain.com"

EDIT: just to clarify, I changed my domain name for a generic 'domain' in this post

Comment: have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: yes, I don't think it's cache related, the error happens randomly

Comment: I'm not so certain its a tomcat issue Apache is the front end and receives the request before passing it to tomcat. Any redirects and such will be handled by apache. There might be a another issue with tomcat config however. I don't use tomcat much so can't help much there.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine is a bit overkill for redirecting domain.com to www.domain.com. This is what I use for my tomcat installations... your ajp lines are fine as well:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    Redirect / http://www.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ProxyPass / http://www.domain.com:8080/ 
    ProxyPassReverse / http://www.domain.com:8080/ 
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *> 
        Order deny,allow 
        Allow from all 
    </Proxy> 
</VirtualHost>
```